# For the SDDM login screen, how do I change the behavior when my laptop lid is closed?

Tags: fedora, power-management, sddm

I have Fedora KDE 37 installed on my laptop.  I use NoMachine to connect to the laptop remotely from my Windows 10 desktop, so I typically leave the lid closed.  I was able to configure my normal desktop session to do nothing when the lid is closed while on external power.  However, if I have to reboot the laptop, I am no longer able to connect to the laptop after it boots up again because it has gone to sleep.  Is it possible to configure the power management settings of SDDM so that it never goes to sleep while on external power?

I tried using `machinectl` to open up a shell as the `sddm` user and use the `qdbus` command to alter the power management settings, but I got an error message stating that the power management service wasn't available.